# Passing a list to a view by Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to pass a list of products to my view. but I Don't know what I'm missing here. When I run it i face with this exception

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[System.Collections.Generic.IList1[DataLayers.Models.mymodel],DataLayers.Services.Repository+d__2]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DataLayers.Models.mymodel]'.

This is my ***IRepository***

```
Task<IList<mymodel>> GetAllProductsAsync();
```

And here is my ***Repository*** (Context injection is omitted for the sake of simplicity )

```
public async Task<IList<mymodel>> GetAllProductsAsync()
    {
        return await _context.mymodel.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This is ***MyController***

```
private readonly IRepository _IRepository;
public MyController(IRepository ThisController)
{
      _IRepository = ThisController;
}


public IActionResult Products()
{
  return View(_IRepository.GetAllProductsAsync());
}
```

And finally Here is ***myView***

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayers.Models.mymodel>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="table-row">
                <td>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DishImg)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Productname)</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProductInfo)</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProductPrice)</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding await like this.. return View(await _IRepository....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider change from:

```
public IActionResult Products()
{
  return View(_IRepository.GetAllProductsAsync());
}
```

To:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Products()
{
  return View(await _IRepository.GetAllProductsAsync());
}
```